# Automatically add method at the end of method chain

Tags: javascript, class, method-chaining

I'm building a JavaScript class and I would like to return a result at the end of a method chain without calling a specific method.

Example 1: `myDate('01/01/2000').add(1, 'day')` should return `01/02/2000`.

Example 2: `myDate('01/01/2000').add(1, 'day').format('MMMM D YYYY')` should return `January 2 2000`.

I know that this is possible using a JS `class` because saw it working in DayJs, I just don't understand how: https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/dev/src/index.js#L77

For now, what I have looks like this:

```
class MyDate {
  constructor(date) {
    this.date = date;
  }

  add(count, unit) {
    this.date = // function
    return this; // to enable method chaining
  }

  format() {
    this.date = // function
    return this.date; // to return the desired result
  }

  get() {
    return this.date;
  }
}

// wrapper function to instantiate class on function call
const myDate = date => new MyDate(date);
```

With this setup, I get the following behavior:

Example 3: `myDate('01/01/2000').add(1, 'day')` returns `{ date: 01/02/2000}` instead of `01/02/2000`.

Example 4: `myDate('01/01/2000').add(1, 'day').format('MMMM D YYYY')` returns `January 2 2000` as expected.

Example 5: `myDate('01/01/2000').add(1, 'day').get()` returns `01/02/2000` but there is that nagging `get()` that I would like to eliminate...

I googled the issue, "js detect end of method chain" and such, but I couldn't find any results that would explain how this works.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In DayJs or MomentJs you must also use `.format ()` to get a date with string otherwise it returns you an object, as your class is doing.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think DayJS is doing anything that's explicitly different. Only you can decide what a function will return--and there's no way to know how someone *using* your API will be using it, e.g., what if they want or need an intermediate value that they still want to be able to chain?

Comment: @AlTheLazyMonkey @Dave Newton, you are both right, thank you for pointing it out to me, I assumed you could return something else than `this` from a chainable method but I was wrong. Here is a little demonstration for those still in doubt: https://replit.com/@RilDev/DayJSClassExamples#index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically speaking `add` method on a class should return the object instance instead of a particular member variable.

What you have as of now is perfect and that's how any user would expect it to work.

Imagine a case where you had to add another member variable, say `time` to your class and you want to chain something like `object.add(1, 'day').add(5, 'hour')`. You can achieve this only if your `add` function returns an instance of your class.

It is also perfectly fine to have to attach a `get()` method at the end. Consider the famous `moment.js` package. Even they have a `format()` method to get the actual date object.

Hope this clarifies your confusion.

Comment: Thank you that's clear. I still wonder though, how is it possible to chain `map` and `filter` on an array? For example `array.map()`, `array.filter()` and `array.map().filter()` all return something usable (not `this`). I guess it's something with `prototype` that I don't get yet... https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/v8/+/refs/heads/master/src/array.js#1253

Comment: prototype is nothing but the class structure. Even with `Array`, what you would have to understand is that in all those function the main class object i.e., `Array` is being returned. Just like we decided in your case as well, to return `MyDate` object instead of some other primitive type

Comment: Looks like we're getting closer to what I was looking for! I've been experimenting (with no success) with the concept of functions sending back the whole class. https://replit.com/@RilDev/ClassChainableMethods#index.js
If possible, could you send me a link to a class that would send back a usable result when used like this: `calculator(1)`, `calculator(1).add(2)`, `calculator(1).add(2).multiply(3)`.
I'm sure it is possible to do with JavaScript!

Comment: @RilDev What do mean by `usable` ? Do you want to use them alongside primitive types ? List down some cases which you think you need to change. One of them would be `console.log` directly without calling `display`. What other use cases do you have ?

Comment: Thanks for putting up with me! I would like to emulate this behavior: `Array(1, 2, 3)` returns `[1, 2, 3]`, `Array(1, 2, 3).map(n => n+1)` returns `[2, 3, 4]` and `Array(1,2,3).map(n => n+1).filter(n => n < 4)` returns `[2, 3]`. In each cases, whether called alone or with a method chain it always sends back a _usable_ `array`, without the need to add a `getValue()` method at the end of the chain. Do you know how to do this? Or how this technique is called?

Comment: @RilDev You seem to getting confused. As you mentioned in all cases it does return a `usable` `Array` since `Array` IS the class you are dealing with. So even in your case, all your functions are returning the same object which is of `MyDate` class which can again be chained to use with other functions. The behaviour is the same in both `Array` and `MyDate`. You dont need to call `getValue` anywhere. Where are you actually needing to call it except for `console.log` ?

Comment: I get it now, arrays are built-in classes that have "hidden" properties such as `length`, that's why we can do `[1, 2, 3].length`. On the other hand, custom made classes expose all the properties they contain in their `this` object (for clarity, I guess). Thank you @Nisanth Reddy for taking the time to clarify for me!

Comment: @RilDev, Bingooo.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back at it, what I wanted to do was a class that had the following features:

- `import myDate from "./myDate.js"`
- `import { isMyDate } from "./myDate.js"`
- No need to use the `new` keyword to instantiate
- Can pass an unlimited number of arguments
- With function chaining
- `console.log(myDate(params))` outputs a custom string `MyDate<date_in_ms)>`
- `${myDate(params)}` outputs a custom string `date_in_ms`

Here is a possible implementation of it:

```
// Custom console.log
// Deno: https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.inspect
const inspect = Symbol.for("Deno.customInspect")
// Node: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_custom
// const inspect = Symbol.for('nodejs.util.inspect.custom');

class MyDate {
  constructor(date = new Date(), options) {
    // Set the class's properties
    this._date = date;
    this._options = options;

    // Run initialization tasks
    this.initialize();
  }

  initialize() {
    // if Date, convert time to milliseconds
    if (this._date instanceof Date) {
      this._date = this._date.getTime();
    }
  }

  // Output the result
  format() {
    return this._date;
  }

  // Chainable function
  add(amount) {
    this._date += amount;
    return this;
  }

  // Output all the parameters past after the first one
  options() {
    return this._options;
  }

  // Custom console.log
  [inspect]() {
    return `MyDate<${this._date}>`;
  }

  // Custom String output
  toString() {
    return `${this._date}`;
  }
}

// Automatically instantiate class
const myDate = (date, ...options) => {
  return new MyDate(date, options);
}

// Stand-alone function
const isMyDate = date => date instanceof MyDate;
// Access the stand-alone funtion from the MyDate instance
myDate.isMyDate = date => isMyDate(date);

export default myDate;
export { isMyDate };
```

Link to Dev.to article: https://dev.to/rildev/modern-es6-class-48pb

Link to live proof-of-concept: https://replit.com/@RilDev/ModernES6Class